# Numerical simulations with multiprocessing much slower than hoped: am I doing anything wrong? Can I speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

**I am running  set of numerical simulations. I need to run some sensitivity analyses on the results**, i.e. calculate and show how much certain outputs change, as certain inputs vary within given ranges. Basically I need to create a table like this, where each row is the result of one model run:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Input 1   |   Input 2   |  Output 1   |  Output 2   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 0.708788979 | 0.614576315 | 0.366315092 | 0.476088865 |
| 0.793662551 | 0.938622754 | 0.898870204 | 0.014915374 |
| 0.366560694 | 0.244354275 | 0.740988568 | 0.197036087 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Each model run is tricky to parallelise, but it shouldn't be too hard to parallelise by getting each CPU to run a different model with different inputs.

**I have put something together with the multiprocessing library, but it is much slower than I would have hoped. Do you have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong / how I can speed it up?** I am open to using a library other than multiprocessing.

**Does it have to do with load balancing?
I must confess I am new to multiprocessing in Python and am not too clear on the differences among map, apply, and apply_async.**

I have made a toy example to show what I mean: I create random samples from a lognormal distribution, and calculate how much the mean of my sample changes as the mean and sigma of the distribution change. This is just a banal example because what matters here is not the model itself, but running multiple models in parallel.

In my example, the times (in seconds) are:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| Million records | Time (parallel) | Time (not parallel) |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|               5 | 24.4            | 18                  |
|              10 | 26.5            | 35.8                |
|              20 | 32.2            | 71                  |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

**Only between a sample size of 5 and 10 million does parallelising bring any benefits. Is this to be expected?**

P.S. I am aware of the [SALib](https://salib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for sensitivity analyses, but, as far as I can see, it doesn't do what I'm after.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

# I store all the possible inputs in a dataframe
tmp = {}
i = 0
for mysigma in np.linspace(0,1,10):
    for mymean in np.linspace(0,1,10):
        i += 1
        tmp[i] = pd.DataFrame({'mean':[mymean],\
           'sigma':[mysigma]})
par_inputs = pd.concat( [tmp[x] for x in tmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)      


def not_parallel(df):
    for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
        myindex = row[0]
        mymean = row[1]
        mysigma = row[2]
        dist = np.random.lognormal(mymean, mysigma, size = n)
        empmean = dist.mean()
        df.loc[myindex,'empirical mean'] = empmean

    df.to_csv('results not parallel.csv')

# splits the dataframe and sets up the parallelisation
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    conc_df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    conc_df.to_csv('results parallelized.csv')
    return conc_df

# the actual function being parallelised
def parallel_sensitivities(data):   
    for row in data.itertuples(index=True):
        myindex = row[0]
        mymean = row[1]
        mysigma = row[2]
        dist = np.random.lognormal(mymean, mysigma, size = n)
        empmean = dist.mean()
        print(empmean)
        data.loc[myindex,'empirical mean'] = empmean
    return data


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
num_partitions = num_cores
n = int(5e6)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    not_parallel(par_inputs)
    time_np = time.time() - start

    start = time.time()
    parallelize_dataframe(par_inputs, parallel_sensitivities)
    time_p = time.time() - start
```

Answer (score 1):

The time differences are for starting the multiple processes up.  To start each process it takes some amount of seconds.  Actual processing time you are doing much better than non-parallel but part of multiprocessing speed increase is accepting the time it takes to start each process.

In this case, your example functions are relatively fast by amount of seconds so you don't see the time gain immediately on a small amount of records.  For more intensive operations on each record you would see much more significant time gains by parallelizing.

> Keep in mind that parallelization is both costly, and time-consuming due to the overhead of the subprocesses that is needed by your operating system. Compared to running two or more tasks in a linear way, doing this in parallel you may save between 25 and 30 percent of time per subprocess, depending on your use-case. For example, two tasks that consume 5 seconds each need 10 seconds in total if executed in series, and may need about 8 seconds on average on a multi-core machine when parallelized. 3 of those 8 seconds may be lost to overhead, limiting your speed improvements.

From [this article.](https://stackabuse.com/parallel-processing-in-python/)

**Edited:**

When using a `Pool()`, you have a few options to assign tasks to the pool.

`multiprocessing.apply_asynch()` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) is used to assign a *single task* and in order to avoid blocking while waiting for that task completion.

`multiprocessing.map_async` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) will chunk an iterable by `chunk_size` and add each chunk to the pool to be completed.

In your case, it will depend on the real scenario you are using, but they aren't exchangeable based on time, rather based on what function you need to run. I'm not going to say for sure which one you need since you used a fake example. I'm guessing you could use `apply_asynch` if you need each function to run and the function is self-contained.  If the function can parallel run over an iterable, you would want to `map_asynch`.

Comment: and would there be any meaningful difference among map, apply and apply_async?

Comment: Added extra answer, but short answer is that they aren't exchangeable because they do different things for different scenarios.  If you are using an iterable, use map.